# cannot be return value overwrite in a loop in c?

Tags: c, loops, return-value, overwrite

I want to return 0.Here, the return value is not overwriting for i=5... Is it possible to return 0?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;

    for(i=2;i<=5;i++){

        if(5%i==0){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `5%i==0` is equivalent to `-5 <= i && i <= 5` but worse due to the division

Comment: Noman, do you see that the `for(i=2;i<=5;i++)` loop only iterates once?  1 of the 2 `return` gets executed.

Comment: You don't really have a loop here, in that the `for` loop never reaches the second iteration.  You could replace the `for(...)` with `i=2;` and the behavior would be unchanged.  `i` starts out as `2`.  Then it evaluates `5%i`, which is `1`.  So it returns `1`.  And if that test hadn't been true, it would return `0`.  Either way, the loop never reaches the second iteration.  The entire function body could be replaced by `return 1;`, and in fact a good optimizing compiler would do just that.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to return 0.

Since the function will return regardless on the first iteration the for loop can be ignored. If we rewrite that code it becomes this:

```c
int i = 2;

if (i <= 5) {
    if (5 % i == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate it please?

Comment: @Noman `return` returns immediately. The execution of the function does not continue after that.

Answer (score 1):

when first loop excuted, i == 2, 5 % i == 1 means i % 5 != 0, so obviously it will return 1, or to say this program has no chance to return 0. And the "return" means the function contains this "return"
will terminate executing when return.

Your requirement is too vague, what do you mean by "I want to return 0", can you explain by literal description?

If you mean you want this loop return only when 5 % i == 0, you should write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;

    for (i = 2; i < =5; i++) {

        if(5 % i == 0){
            continue;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to understand what you are trying to ask is that 5 is divisible by 5(when i = 5) and so it should return `0` but it must be returning `1`. The reason for this is that when the first time the loop executes, the if condition is checked `(5%2 == 0)`, which is false. Thus, the else block is executed which returns 1.

If this is the case then you can do this:

```
for(i=2;i<=5;i++){

    if(5%i==0){
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
```

Now whole for loop will be executed, and so what you desired (what I think you desired) you will get.